# Bagplot function error

Tags: r

I am using the bagplot function within the aplpack package and often get this error:

```
Error in chull(pg[, 1], pg[, 2]) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
```

Here's an example of data for which this happens:

```
bagplot(c(-4.66, -2.62, -3.65 ,-3.07 ,-4.91, -4.56 ,-3.79, -3.10, -3.01), 
          c(2.14, -7.18, -0.15 , 2.67, -2.49, -0.89 , 0.96 , 0.59, -4.59))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: i do not get this error when running your code using R version 2.15.0 64-bit for mac

Comment: Thanks for this. After I saw your comment I tried my code on a mac and sure enough, it worked. However, it wasn't long before I got another error. For example: 

`bagplot(c(1.852, -1.740, 2.170, 4.745, -5.858, -3.521, 3.001, -6.139, -1.513, -1.384, 1.957, -0.023, -0.495, -2.401, -7.966),c(2.310, -2.752, 1.492, -2.929, 3.487, 1.343, 2.976, -1.260, -1.153, -0.384, 4.735, 3.978, 0.103, -1.650, -2.209))` 

produces the same error. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Update: I have been in touch with the author of the package who has resolved the errors. New version of the package should be available soon!